# Branch cut $\frac{\ln(z+i)}{1 +z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points, riemann-sphere

For each of the following functions $$ \ln\frac{z−1}{ z+1},$$ $$\frac{\ln(z+i)}{1 +z^2},$$ $$\ln(z^2−1),$$ find location and order of the branch points, and give a valid branch cut.

Can you help me with these?
Any hint for example 2.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I know that in first case branch points are $z=1$ and $z=-1$ but i don't know which branch cut i need to chose $(-\infty,-1)$ or $(1,\infty)$ , $(-1,1)$

Comment: Well done!  The corresponding branch cuts are not unique.  In fact, they need not even be straight lines.